# Вызвать функцию в разных потоках C++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Можно ли выполнять разные участки кода одной функции в разных потоках? Например:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
void make(){
  some code //Выполнить в потоке a
  some code 2 // Выполнить в потоке b
}
int main(){
  thread a(make);
  thread b(make);
  some code 3; 
}
```

Comment: да, но по логике, вам нужно идентифицировать участки кода для компилятора (положив их в разные методы)

Comment: Можно и в рамках набросанного вами прототипа функции `make()`, только скорее всего не реентарабельно. Код в make должен использовать внешнюю общую переменную (понятно, защищаемую мьютексом) и тогда одна часть может, изменив эту переменную, направить другую часть кода (вызванную позже в другом потоке) на 2-ю часть кода. Однако, проще и эффективнее пойти по пути, предложенном в ответе @VTT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без проблем, стоит только передать в процедуру какой-то идентификатор, позволяющий определить, какой из кусков следует выполнять в данном потоке:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void make(char const code_id)
{
    switch(code_id)
    {
        case 'a':
        {
            // some code
        }
        break;
        case 'b':
        {
            // some code 2
        }
        break;
        default:
        {
            // do nothing...
        }
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
  ::std::thread a(&::make, 'a');
  ::std::thread b(&::make, 'b');
  a.join();
  b.join();
  return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hka4x3MBr6b7Di0q)

Answer (score 3):

Именно так, как вы пишете - нет. 
Нечто подобное позволяет OpenMP - например, распараллелить цикл, но это не совсем C++, это расширение все же...
Но! никто не мешает сделать так: разбить `make()` на две функции, вроде

```
void make()
{
    first();
    second();
}
```

и уже их выполнить параллельно.